# Creating a Sliding Scale Similar to Noom

Tags: android, user-interface, android-sliding

I want to create a sliding weight scale for my app like the one in screen shot. I cannot figure out which Layout or UI components to use. Please Suggest a way or tutorial to do this.

Thanks

[Link to screenshot](http://anshulapps.in/scale.png)

Comment: You need to create a custom view which draws the scale points and takes touch event to handle the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Did not get any reference so I tried creating it on my own. Check it out in Github.

[SlidingScale - GitHub](https://github.com/Anshul47/SlidingScale)